# Sending Python App logs directly to SOLR

Tags: python-3.x, logging, solr

I am currently using python logging with file handler to write the logs. However, was wondering if there is a way to send logs straight to an external system such as SOLR? I see there is a way of sending it to logstash, however would prefer if I could send it straight to SOLR. Is there any way to do that?